# eclipse doesn't show compilation error but ant failed on compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, ant

I have the following code:

```
SortedSetByDoubleValue<String,Double> set = SortedSetByDoubleValue.create();
```

It has no compilation errors on eclipse, but when running `javac` with ant it failed on compilation:

```
[javac] .../TestSortedSetByComparable.java:55: incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) E,T exist so that ....SortedSetByDoubleValue<E,T> conforms to ....SortedSetByDoubleValue<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>
    [javac] found   : <E,T>....SortedSetByDoubleValue<E,T>
    [javac] required: ....SortedSetByDoubleValue<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>
    [javac]             SortedSetByDoubleValue<String,Double> set = SortedSetByDoubleValue.create();
    [javac]                                                                                      ^
    [javac] 5 errors
```

however when changing the code to:

```
SortedSetByDoubleValue<String,Double> set = SortedSetByDoubleValue.<String,Double>create();
```

it is compiled with no errors.

The ant target is:

```
<javac srcdir="." fork="yes" executable="/usr/java/1.6.0.10/bin/javac" verbose="yes" destdir="build" debug="on" failonerror="true" source="1.6">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="../ant/dist">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="../external/powermock-1.2.5/">
                        <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
                <pathelement path="${external_jars}" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
```

Comment: Please. Post enough code so that others can reproduce it.

Comment: I think I gave enough code, what else would you expect?

Comment: so if I compile that one line of code, I'll get the compiler error message?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard my answer is the only correct answer. "it's probably a compiler problem", that counts as an answer?

Comment: @irreputable - yes this line of code is giving error when compiling with sun JDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse uses a different compiler to the regular javac that ant would use. However it is more likely to be a problem of using a different version of Java e.g. 5.0 vs 6

EDIT: Try the following

```
SortedSetByDoubleValue<String,Double> set =
    SortedSetByDoubleValue<String,Double>.create();
```

Comment: as far as I can tell both are running with 1.6 JDK

Comment: As far as I know there have been no changes in type inference rules between Java 5 and 6. And type inferences is the area with the most differences between the compilers. More often than not the bug is with `javac` (i.e. the Eclipse compiler is usually closer to the spec).

Comment: I tried using sun compiler with ant and it is not working. the same jdk is configured for the eclipse project.

Comment: Achim is again right. The safest bet IMHO is not to rely on type inference at all if one needs to employ different compilers.